# How to unit test an extension method converting an Action to a Func?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, delegates, extension-methods

I am writing a small Functional C# library in which I have defined a `Unit` `type as well as a bunch of extension methods to convert:

- `Action`
- `Action<T1>`
- `Func<T1, T2>`
- Etc.

To:

- `Func<Unit>`
- `Func<T1, Unit>`
- `Func<T1,T2, Unit>`
- Etc.

```cs
public static partial class ActionExtensions
{
    public static Func<Unit> ToFunc(this Action action) =>
    () =>
    {
        action();
        return Unit.Default;
    };

    public static Func<T, Unit> ToFunc<T>(this Action<T> action) =>
        t =>
        {
            action(t);
            return Unit.Default;
        };

    public static Func<T1, T2, Unit> ToFunc<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action) =>
        (t1, t2) =>
        {
            action(t1, t2);
            return Unit.Default;
        };

     // other methods...
```

`Unit` being defined as follows:

```cs
public readonly struct Unit : IEquatable<Unit>
{
    public static readonly Unit Default = new Unit();

    public override int GetHashCode() => 
        0;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is Unit;

    public bool Equals(Unit other) =>
        true;

    public static bool operator ==(Unit left, Unit right) =>
        true;

    public static bool operator !=(Unit left, Unit right) =>
        false;
}
```

I am wondering how to unit test those extension methods.

Should I perform some sort of reflection to analyse the return type as well as parameters of the `Func`, should I check that when calling the `Func` this calls the underlying `Action` method?

Any thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to pass an action that sets a boolean value to true when the action is invoked, and then test the result of your extension method. That proves the expected behavior, which is

- action is invoked
- function is returned with default unit

For example,

```
[Test] public void ToFuncForGivenActionInvokesAction()
{
    // arrange
    bool invoked = false;
    Action action = () => invoked = true;

    // act
    var func = action.ToFunc();

    // assert
    func().Should().Be(Unit.Default);
    invoked.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

In the above

- I'm using [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) for asserting proof, but you can use whatever you want of course
- Don't bother checking `func` for null. Testing the result of `func()` covers that case. Less noise.
- Repeat for your actions that take parameters.

I'd skip all the reflection. I suspect the number of methods under test is low enough that some repeating of code is OK because that is more readable than contortions needed for reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Using a mocking framework like [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io) you can easily assert that a given method/action has been called and also that the values of the passed arguments are as expected.

*In the example below, I'am using the [xUnit](https://xunit.net) test framework.*

The assert `testDummy.Received().Run("foobar", 123);` will fail the test if

1. the `Run` method hasn't been executed
2. the `Run` method would have received other argument values than `foobar` and `123`.

---

```
public interface ITestDummy
{
    void Run(String arg1, Int32 arg2);
}

public class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {   
        var testDummy = Substitute.For<ITestDummy>();

        Action<String, Int32> action = testDummy.Run;  
        Func<String, Int32, Unit> func = action.ToFunc();

        var result = func("foobar", 123);

        testDummy.Received().Run("foobar", 123);
        Assert.Equal(result, Unit.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `Received().Run(Arg.Is("foobar"), Arg.Is(123))`?

Comment: Using `Received().Run("foobar", 123)` is fine. When asserting, the passed in parameters (here: `foobar` and `123`) are the values that get compared to the ones that were used at the actual call of the method (here: `func("foobar", 123)`). Asserting with `Received().Run("baz", 789);` would make the test fail.